# Laravel formatting api reply

Tags: laravel

I need to formatting the response of my api,

At the moment the api controller is very simple

```
    public function index()
{
    $data = WeDayMMA::take(30)->get(); 
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

But I got a problem, some data here are store as time, but when i get the models, laravel convert my Time in DatatTime adding the actual data before ex: "TTmin":"2021-11-19T21:05:42.000000Z" should be just "TTmin":"21:05:42.000000Z" can I, and how, fomrat the data before sending?? which is the best performance way?

Comment: Create/use an [API resource](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources)?

Comment: mmh interesting, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

> When building an API, you may need a transformation layer that sits between your Eloquent models and the JSON responses that are actually returned to your application's users. For example, you may wish to display certain attributes for a subset of users and not others, or you may wish to always include certain relationships in the JSON representation of your models. Eloquent's resource classes allow you to expressively and easily transform your models and model collections into JSON.
> [Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources)

Comment: Thank you for clarification, sincerly I have a low knowledge of Laravel and all the system, but in my case I just needed to plot out the value, is just a data log, but creating an api resource, and so creating a layer between model and api it's olso a safety enanchment?